# If $f'(x_0)=\infty$ does it follow that $f$ must be continuous at $x_0$ on one side at least?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f'(x_0)=\infty$ does it follow that $f$ must be continuous at $x_0$ on one side at least?

I am sort of convinced that this might be true but I am not sure how to prove this. Any hints would be much appreciated?

Comment: You mean like $f(x)=1/x$ and $x_0=0$?

Comment: Or rather, I suppose that $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)$ in the above example is infinity.

Comment: Oops you are right! This is a counterexample.